# Understand what's underhood SQLAlchemy query and its latency

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy, latency

Here's my pseudo code for SQL query using SQLAlchemy:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import query
query = MyClass.query

if arg1:
   query = query.filter(MyClass.f1 == arg1)

if arg2:
   query = query.filter(MyClass.f2 == arg2)

if arg3:
   query = query.filter(MyClass.f3 == arg3)

res = jsonify(requests=[r.to_dict() for r in query])

return res
```

I calculated the time duration for each of step in the code, and surprised to find `query.filter` is quite fast (~0.0001s) while rate-limiting step is `jsonify(requests=[r.to_dict() for r in query])`(~0.3s !) How to explain this?

Also here's my log:

```
f1 time 0.0002
f2 time 0.0001
2023-05-04 09:37:09,667 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT 1
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:SELECT 1
2023-05-04 09:37:09,667 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:()
2023-05-04 09:37:09,668 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:BEGIN (implicit)
2023-05-04 09:37:09,669 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT ...
...
...
jsonify time 0.31
...
```

From the log traces, seems all real SQL operation seems done after `query.filter`?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLAlchemy methods like `filter()`, `group_by()`, etc. don't execute the query. They construct a query object that contains an internal representation of the query -- what tables are being queried, the columns to return, the table relationships. Each time you call one of these functions (often they're chained to build up the desired query), it returns a new query object with the specified changes.

The query isn't executed until you call a method that returns results, such as `to_dict()`. At this time, the internal representation is converted to SQL, which is sent to the database. The results are then collected into the dictionary.

So `.filter()` doesn't tell SQLAlchemy to filter the results itself, it just tells it that when it creates the query it should add appropriate `WHERE` conditions that make the database do the requested filtering.

Comment: I just tried `print(str(len([record for record in query])))` right after `query = query.filter(MyClass.f1 == arg1)` and I can see expected row number is printed. So  `len([record for record in query]` is also execution. Thanks I think now all make sense!

Comment: When you use `query` as an iterator, it executes the query and returns the results.

Comment: Anything that needs to return the results triggers conversion to SQL and execution of the query.